# Rewrite Iterator from JSONObject to JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have an iterator for `JSONObjects` but unfortunately I get a `JSONArray` from my JSON-data.

Now I want to rewrite it. I'm pretty new to Java. Can somebody tell me how to approach this?

I use the json.simple library.

```
public class JSONIteratorAuthor implements Iterator <Author> {

   private Iterator<JSONObject> authors;

   public JSONIteratorAuthor(JSONObject jsonObject){

       this.authors = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("authors")).iterator();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasNext() {
       return this.authors.hasNext();
   }

   public Author next() {
       if(this.hasNext()){
           Author a = new Author(0, "", "");
           JSONObject authorNode = (JSONObject) authors.next();
           a.setFirstName((String) authorNode.get("first_name"));
           a.setLastName((String) authorNode.get("last_name"));
           return a;
       }
       else {
       return null;
       }
   }    
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this work? `private Iterator<JSONArray> authors;` and `JSONArray authorNode = authors.next();` You should also mention which json lib you are using.

Comment: It does not work. At the lines `a.setFirstName((String) authorNode.get("first_name"));` and `a.setLastName((String) authorNode.get("last_name"));` i get the error message: "no suitable method found for get(String)" since JSONArray does not have that method. Also shouldn't the line `public JSONIteratorAuthor(JSONObject jsonObject)` be changed to  `public JSONIteratorAuthor(JSONArray jsonObject)` since i want to iterate a JSONArray?

Comment: Don't know. That's why I asked for the json lib, you are using. As it seems, you do not use "org.json". You should mention the full package name of `JSONArray/JSONObject` and the name of the jar file you included in your classpath.

Comment: my bad. i'm using the json.simple library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of information about the structure of your JSON data, I assume the following:

1. You have got a `JSONArray` object to call the constructor with
2. This `JSONArray` contains `JSONObject`s
3. These `JSONObject`s have got suitable key-value pairs

In that case the following solution should work. It takes advantage of the fact that `JSONArray` itself is iteratable.

```
private Iterator<JSONObject> authors;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public JSONIteratorAuthor(JSONArray array){
   authors = array.iterator();
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
   return authors.hasNext();
}

@Override
public Author next() {
   if (hasNext()) {
       Author a = new Author(0, "", "");
       JSONObject authorNode = authors.next();
       a.setFirstName((String) authorNode.get("first_name"));
       a.setLastName((String) authorNode.get("last_name"));
       return a;
   }
   else {
       return null;
   }
}
```

EDIT: Given your actual input, the solution is simple: The array contains objects, which contain yet other arrays. So for the above code to work, you have to do the following (where `parsedJson` is that, what you get from your actual input file (as posted in dropbox):

```
Iterator array = ((JSONArray) parsedJson).iterator();           
while (array.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) array.next();
    JSONArray authors = (JSONArray)json.get("authors");
    JSONIteratorAuthor test = new JSONIteratorAuthor(authors);
    while (test.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(test.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: my JSON data looks like this: http://pastebin.com/cD9tzSjL  your code gives me objects  with value "null" for the names.

Comment: i think i have to direct the iterator to the key-value "authors". But i have no idea how i can do this

Comment: I figured it out myself already, thank you for your help nonetheless. it helped me to understand the actual problem

Comment: @Anjo9 to mark it as useful click on the upper arrow next to question. Below that is a green mark to accept the answer. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers